# Do I need a registered number to use twilio as a messaging service to send SMS to 2 employees/day?

Tags: twilio, sms

I've created a power automate flow that sends an email and (hopefully) a text message (via Twilio) to an On Call Developer (setup using a sharepoint list/calendar) whenever a Batch Process fails. It's ready to go, but Twilio is saying that the number is unregistered and is only sporadically sending SMS messages during testing.  We aren't sending huge volumes of SMS messages and we don't need our single on-call developer to opt in.  Is there an easier way for me to get this to work consistently using twilio?

Setup a messaging service within Twilio.  Waited for it to be approved.  It was rejected due to not having an opt-in:  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/30896

Is there a simpler way for me to set this up to use internally?